# Firefox OS Simple Push not working properly

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firefox-os

I have problems with simple push on ffos. Here is my code:

```
    var endpoint;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        registerPush();
        navigator.mozSetMessageHandler("push", function(message) {
            if(message.pushEndpoint == endpoint) {
                console.log("push notification: "+message.version);
            }
        });
        navigator.mozSetMessageHandler("push-register", function() {
            registerPush();
        });
    });
    function registerPush() {
        var req = navigator.push.register();
        req.onsuccess = function(e) {
            endpoint = e.target.result;
            console.log(endpoint);
        }
    }
```

It is working ok when i start the app, but after few minutes if i try to send a push to the endpoint, nothing happens. But when i call the `registerPush();` function, everithing works again for few minutes.

Comment: Can you please post your app manifest file?  Do you have 'register-push' listed in the messages section?  See here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Simple_Push#Modify_manifest_file

Answer (score 0):

It is said that there may be a bug. Some routers may are filtering the push notifications, so that may be the problem. I think It may be bypassed using a 3G connection.